# wp post metadata showing in backend but not frontend / same code

Tags: wordpress, metadata

**Situation:**

using a php file *(table_template.php)* with include_once to show  meta data. Using this template in the backend (inside a metabox) shows everything as it should - using the same template on the frontend (inside a post) the table metadata do not show (but other meta data from custom fields do).

**var dump in the backend:**

string(65) "[["test value 1","test value 2","test value 3"],["test value a","test value b","test value c"]]"

**var dump on the frontend:**

string(6) "[[""]]"

**code from *table_template.php*:**

```
<?php

/* TEMPLATE TO RENDER THE TABLE (AS PREVIEW) IN THE BACKEND AND FRONTEND */

global $post;
$table_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'psg_table_meta', true ) ? 
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'psg_table_meta', true ) : '[[""]]';
$t = json_decode( $table_meta );
$c_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
$c = get_post( $c_id );


?>

<div class="psg_box_table">
    <table class="psg_table ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $t[ 0 ] as $col ): ?>
                <th>
                    <?php echo $col; ?>
                </th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $t as $idx => $row ): ?>
            <?php if ( $idx == 0 )
               continue; ?>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $row as $col ): ?>
                <td>
                    <div class="psg_table_content">
                        <?php echo str_replace( '"', '&quot;', $col ) ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!--END SIZING CHART TABLE -->
```

**How i load the Template:**

```
include_once( "table_template.php" );
```

Comment: The issue was, that i should not check for the postID (the table meta data is not directly in the post, but in a selected/linked post within it. So i had to replace $table_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'psg_table_meta', true ) ?  with $table_meta = get_post_meta( $psg_selected, 'psg_table_meta', true ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that i should not check for the postID (the table meta data is not directly in the post, but in a selected/linked post within it. So i had to replace

```
$table_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'psg_table_meta', true ) ?
```

with

```
$table_meta = get_post_meta( $psg_selected, 'psg_table_meta', true ) ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the template inside loop of `WP_Query`, then replace

```
$post->ID
```

with

```
get_the_ID();
```

Also check the `psg_table_meta` key is correct one.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. While it's not exactly the correct answer, you lead me to the right path and i'd like to thank you for that and accept your answer as correct.